# SQL Server : assistance with INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, adventureworks

I have a problem where I need to create new entries in the `SpecialOfferProduct` table. I am applying my created discount (`SpecialOfferID = 20`) to all products that have an inventory greater than 1800 but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. this is my code.

```
INSERT INTO Sales.SpecialOfferProduct (ProductID SpecialOfferID)
    SELECT ProductID 
    FROM Production.ProductInventory 
    GROUP BY ProductID 
    HAVING SUM(Quantity) > 1800, 20 AS SpecialOfferID;
```

It's from the `AdventureWorks2012` database

Thanks

Comment: if your this code is working then issue is in insert `SELECT ProductID FROM Production.ProductInventory GROUP BY ProductID HAVING sum(Quantity) > 1800, 20 AS SpecialOfferID;`

while inserting i don't this you need alias like this `(ProductID SpecialOfferID)` ans if specialofferid is another column then this should be next to productid in select query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you means it

```
INSERT INTO Sales.SpecialOfferProduct (ProductID ,SpecialOfferID)
SELECT ProductID, 20 AS SpecialOfferID FROM Production.ProductInventory 
GROUP BY ProductID 
HAVING sum(Quantity) > 1800;
```